# Why reading byte array to an Object throws java.io.StreamCorruptedException?

Tags: java

I have a requirement to read a stream of bytes from a remote system. The remote system has its own client API to read the bytes. But at my end, I have to convert the byte array to a POJO. While doing so, I am getting error `java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header:`.

To test the functionality, I wrote following program to convert a `String` to a `byte array` and then convert the byte array to an `Object`.

```
public class ByteToObject {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      final String str = "Tiger";
      System.out.println("\nByte array for string '" + str + "' --> \n" + Arrays.toString(getByteArray(str)));
      System.out.println("Object read --> " + getObject(getByteArray(str)));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private static byte[] getByteArray(final String str) throws Exception {
    return str.getBytes(CharEncoding.UTF_8);
  }

  private static Object getObject(final byte[] byteArray) throws Exception {
    InputStream byteArrayStream = null;
    ObjectInputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        byteArrayStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);
        inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayStream);
        return inputStream.readObject();
      } finally {
        if(null != byteArrayStream) {
          byteArrayStream.close();
        }
        if(null != inputStream) {
          inputStream.close();
        }
     } 
  }
}
```

The output is:

```
Byte array for string 'Tiger' --> 
[84, 105, 103, 101, 114]
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 54696765
Object read --> null
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:299)
    at com.demo.serialize.ByteToObject.getObject(ByteToObject.java:41)
    at com.demo.serialize.ByteToObject.main(ByteToObject.java:24)
```

Appreciate if someone can help what is wrong here?

Comment: String to byte array? does the remote part send you a String?

Comment: which line fails?  Looks like you are getting an object not a string

Comment: The remote systems sends either a string or a custom object. I just wrote this simple program to check if there is any issue in deserialization.

Comment: @Java1, the line `inputStream.readObject()` fails. And, for my real use case, I do not know if the remote system sends me a string or a custom POJO. Appreciate if you could elaborate **but you are trying to convert a serialized object to a String!**

Comment: I suggest you never mix text and binary unless you like confusion.  In this case you are trying to read text as a binary object which is never going to work.  You have a better chance of understanding something written in Japanese if you only know English.

Comment: I know I should not mix, but I have no choice; the remote system stores everything as byte array and a different system produces messages into that remote system which I have to read. Is there a better solution to handle such a system integration scenario?

Comment: @Niranjan 0x54696765 is "Tige". You can't deserialize that. It's not a serialized object, it's a String. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: you are using inputStream.readObject() but you do not have a serialised object, you just have a String.

Comment: If the remote system really does as you describe you have a really broken protocol.  I assume you can get text and or binary data in the same stream.  You would have to parse the stream with your own parser to find when a text or binary object is sent and when it finished and cut up the messages yourself. Once the messages are cut up, decoding them is relatively simple.

Comment: Or else they are sending everything as a serialized object, including the strings. But your test program proves nothing. It is just a mistake. What's the *real* problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

Because you corrupted the stream. You shouldn't have had the serialized data in a `String` in the first place. The round trip back to `byte[]` is lossy. Just pass the `byte[]` array around.

Repeat after me. `String` is not a container for binary data. Write out 100 times ;-)

**EDIT** 0x54696765 is "Tige". You didn't have a serialized object in the first place. You already had the `String`.

NB You don't need to close the `ByteArrayInputStream` if you are closing the wrapping `ObjectInputStream`, and as that only wraps a `ByteArrayInputStream` you don't really need to close that either.

Comment: I know Strings in Java do not contain binary data, but I explained why I have to do it. I am reading this binary data from a remote system and that remote system stores everything as binary data. Now, a different system in my organization produces data into that remote system which I have to read. The data could be a string and could be a custom object. Do you have any other solution to tackle such a situation?

Comment: You don't 'have to do it'. You should read the raw data first, decide what it is, whether serialized data or a String, and *then* try to convert it accordingly. By reading it as a `String` you have already pre-judged the issue.